# What is maximal block size could be read into memory of a process?

Tags: c++, boost

I need to read a large file, but along program parameters an user also provides a block size. Each block must be read into memory in order to make a hash of the block. How do I say that this is a maximal block size I can read into a process memory?

Say, I am using `mapped_region` from Boost. There is a parameter `size` which is a size of region.
So I would like to know the maximal size I can pass into the constructor of `mapped_region`.

Comment: You may have an OS-specific limit. Theoretically, you have a maximum of `size_t` as far as C++ is concerned. For hashing and if using Windows you may benefit from File Mapping that does the dirty work for you.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Ok, and how do I get to know the limit in OS-independent way?

Comment: For x64 systems this is almost unlimited (from a pratical perspective).

Comment: It depends on the API called and its specific parameters. As said, if you want to provide a buffer to a third party library for hashing, reading the file in blocks would suit the hashing algorithm of your choise (since they are also block-based), or you can use File Mapping.

Comment: @alexander.sivak You don't. This is highly architecture and system dependent

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann I need to pass a block to a hash function, but how do I know in advance that this is maximal block size and I cannot read bigger blocks? Otherwise I cannot avoid a runtime buffer overflow error.

Comment: You have to read the function's docs about how it expects the memory you feed to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum implementation limit for the maximum size of an object specified by the C++ standard is 262 144 bytes. An implementation is allowed to support larger objects and many do.

Another limitation is the size of the address space. In a 32 bit address space for example, no larger than 2<sup>32</sup> bytes of memory can be addressed. Furthermore, some of that address space (typically half, or a quarter) will be reserved to the operating system kernel.

Furthermore, a potential limitation is the amount of available physical memory on the system (including swap) - unless the operating system over-commits memory, and the memory of the object is never written to.

Also, some operating system may limit the total amount of memory that a process may allocate, such as `RLIMIT_DATA` on POSIX.